# Are questions about naming classes relevant on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are questions concerning class names relevant on any of the Stack Exchange sites?

I'm not referring to discussions about the merits of one naming convention over another.  But, questions actually referring to the *meaning* of a class name and what would be most appropriate.

For example, I have a question in regards to naming a domain object.  I am working with a [publicly available API](http://developer.github.com/) that returns back a [User](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/) object with a lot of data.  They also return back a [Follower](http://developer.github.com/v3/users/followers/) object with not quite as much data.  I have a question in regards to what would be the most appropriate way of naming, and dealing with, these different domain objects; keeping in mind that a Follower is really just a subset of  User and that other non-Follower objects return exactly the same information.  Perhaps the answer leads to something other than a naming issue but the point is that *the initial question is one about naming classes*.

Is this appropriate for any of the Stack Exchange sites and, if so, which one?

Comment: I certainly hope there is.  It sounds like a grey area between SO and Programmers, but I don't spend enough time on the latter to really know what's acceptable there.

Answer (score 10):

In general, understanding the meaning of well-known programming terminology used in names would be on-topic for Programmers:

> What is a delegate? What things count as delegates?

Similarly, understanding the appropriate use of design patterns (which would likely indirectly lead to answering a question about naming) would be on-topic for Programmers as well:

> I'm working on X problem: would using the observer pattern be the most appropriate way to handle it?

And finding the correct terminology to describe a concept is *usually* on-topic on Programmers:

> I've used this pattern that looks similar to other code I've seen, but I'm not sure how to refer to it so I don't look dumb in front of my coworkers

But many of these types of "concept naming" questions get too far into bike-shedding and neologisms and thus aren't constructive:

> Can you think of a name to call this pattern I just made up?

Likewise, naming advice for your classes, methods, et al is not constructive anywhere, including Programmers. It ultimately rests on who's reading the code and what the internal naming conventions for the project are:

> What should I call this method that does X?

Subsequently, understanding people's code would not be on-topic for Programmers (or Stack Overflow) either as it requires private knowledge about the intent of a person we don't know:

> Why did my coworker name this method `punchFluffyBunnies()`?